# rnorm() gives me x coordinate or Y coordinate of normal distribution graph?

Tags: r, probability, normal-distribution

I am very new to statistics and R, and hence I might be asking very silly questions.

`rnorm()` function gives me standard normal random variables with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.
Do these variables belong to x-axis or y-axis of normal distribution graph?

Comment: Side note: R is not a tool, it is a complete software.

Comment: What's a "normal distribution graph"? An ecdf? a QQ plot? a histogram? something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x axis. The `rnorm` function returns simulated **values** from a rv with a normal distribution, given the `mean` an `sd` parameters.

Comment: what is this RV?

Comment: rv = Random Variable

Comment: What's the rationale here? There is no connection here between the answer and the definition of `rnorm()`.  I see no reason why a normal distribution should not be plotted any way you want, so the variable in question could be on the y axis when we are seeing it as a response, on the x axis if plotted in a conventional histogram, etc., etc.

Comment: Because he is talking about de density/distribution function. When you ploy these functions, in the x axis, you have the variable, in the y axis you have density/probability

Comment: There is no reference to density in the question. In any case, you can plot density functions any way you like. It's just a majority convention, in my view, to have density on the vertical axis. Whether it's a convention only or there is a stronger rationale, is what is missing from your answer. As @Glen_b also comments, there are several different plots that could qualify as normal distribution graphs.

Comment: Yes, you *can* plot a function anyway you want, but in literature, you will always find the variable in the x axis in a density/distribution function. He is new to statistics. At least for me, that means that when he says "normal distribution graph" he has a Gaussian bell in mind. Anyway, let he himself make this point clear.

Comment: @toneloy & Nick Cox Yes, I clearly mentioned I am  new to statistics, and I am referring to bell curve only by normal distribution. And all the graphs mentioned by Glen_b are big things for me which I am not aware yet. And thanks to toneloy for understanding my level and giving a simple answer without confusing me with so much of the questions for which i dont have any answer..

Comment: @toneloy Quantile plots are distribution function plots with axes reversed, modulo some small details. Violin plots have density shown horizontally. I could add other examples. So the very strong claim "always" is just incorrect about the literature.

Comment: There was, and is, absolutely no intention on my part to confuse the OP (nor, am I sure, was that the intent of @Glen_b). The problem is otherwise. First, the OP's precise question just was not clear to me, nor to @Glen_b; that is why we **both** asked for clarifications. The recent comment specifying a bell is thus helpful (and should be edited into the question). Second, questions are not the unique property of the OP; threads here should be of interest to many people, including people at a variety of levels.